# Call a JavaScript function when user leaves a page

Tags: javascript

I want the function `pageleave()` to be called before the user exits a page. But I can't seem to get it to work correctly, I searched the web for a couple hours and can't find a solution. Here is the code I came up with. It runs when the page loads instead of when the page unloads.

```
window.onbeforeunload = pageleave;

        function pageleave() {
            $.post("<?php echo dirname( get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url') ); ?>/ajax/videocanle.php", { videoID: "<?php echo $videoID; ?>" },
                function(data) {
                    if ( data != "\nsuccess"){
                        alert ("Sorry but there was an unexpected error, please try again");
                    }

                });

        }
```

That is the current revision, it still doesn't run the function before the page unloads. The function does work thou, I tested it with a simple input button.

```
<input type="button" value="test function" onclick="pageleave()" />
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to assign a reference to the function, not the result of calling the function (which is what the `()` does). Remove the `()`:

```
window.onunload = pageleave();
```

(You may also want to use the `onbeforeunload` event instead of `onunload`, and also return some kind of confirmation message so that your Ajax request has a chance to complete.)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I tried that and it didn't work, here is the code I used just in case I missed something.

window.onbeforeunload=pageleave;
  
function pageleave() {
 $.post("<?php echo dirname( get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url') ); ?>/ajax/videocanle.php", { videoID: "<?php echo $videoID; ?>" } );
    
   }

Answer (score 3):

```
window.onunload=pageleave;

        function pageleave() {
            $.post("<?php echo dirname( get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url') ); ?>/ajax/videocanle.php", { videoID: "<?php echo $videoID; ?>" } );    
        }
```

Comment: It can be `onbeforeunload` also.

Answer (score 2):

You want to pass a reference to the function. In your example you were calling the function in your assignment statement. Try this:

```
window.onunload = function() {
  $.post("<?php echo dirname( get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url') ); ?>/ajax/videocanle.php", { 
    videoID: "<?php echo $videoID; ?>"
  });    
};
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, but I tried that, and it didn't work. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function()  {
  $.post("<?php echo dirname( get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url') ); ?>/ajax/videocanle.php", { 
    videoID: "<?php echo $videoID; ?>"
  });    
};
```